# How to call a method of type T passing T As string or "T"

Tags: c#

I have something like this

```
public void FunctionName<T>(){

}
```

and to call this you need something like this

```
sub main(){
    FunctionName<Integer>();
}
```

my question is can i pass the Integer as "Integer"?

```
sub main(){
    FunctionName<"Integer">();
}
```

or is there any other way to that

Ok here is my actual code

```
private static T Convert<T>(DataRow row) where T : new()
{
    T model = new T();
    Type modelType = model.GetType();
    FieldInfo[] fields = null;
    FieldInfo field = default(FieldInfo);
    Type fieldType = null;
    string fieldName = null;

    fields = modelType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

    foreach ( field in fields) {
        fieldType = field.FieldType;
        fieldName = field.Name.Replace("_", string.Empty);
        Interaction.CallByName(model, fieldName, Microsoft.VisualBasic.CallType.Set, GetValue(row, fieldName, fieldType.Name));
    }

    return model;
}


static void main(){
    Student s;

    s = Convert<Student>(DatabaseRow);
}
```

The problem here is I just can only get the Student as
string ("Student") from somewhere that will use this code
Any other solution to get this right?

Comment: WTF is with `sub` stuff?

Comment: @Tamir: This question looks perfectly clear to me.

Comment: Are you sure you're programming in C#? Maybe you should change the tags of your question to include the actual language ('sub' sounds like VB)

Comment: sorry for sub stuff, yup i'm coding on C# and vb, maybe i should look it more first before posting it here, my mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without seeing more of your code, it's hard to say for sure whether you have a legitimate use-case for invoking a method like this.  But regardless, assuming `FunctionName` is contained in class `Foo`, then you can invoke the method using reflection:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var typeName = "System.Int32";
var method = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("FunctionName");
var genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(Type.GetType(typeName));
genericMethod.Invoke(foo, new Type[0]);
```

Note that we can't use `Integer` since that's not the real type name.   (it's either `int` or `Int32` in C# but only `Int32` is legal for `GetType` since `int` is baked into the compiler)  Also, all the usual caveats about getting a type via `Type.GetType` apply here (there are many situations where it won't find your custom type).

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't do that. You should use generics only if the type is known at compile-time. That's the whole point of generics: enforce compile-time safety. If the type is not known at compile-time, as in your case, you could use Reflection or some other technique depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to do. Use Reflections to call the function but that technique returns the classname as string instead of the actual class type

Answer (score 0):

In additin to Darin's answer: If the function was not compiled for the specified type (simply because it's never explicitely called for this type), the code is not available at all.