# How to set Generic Type T as string in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I Have the full name of a type as string and I would like to use this string to tell type of a generic method. see this

```
      string typeStr ="Dll.NameSpace.MyType";
      var list = new List<Dll.NameSpace.MyType>();//should put typeStr here
      var result = call.SomeGenericMethod<...>(obj);//should put typeStr here
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817928/how-to-call-a-method-of-type-t-passing-t-as-string-or-t) didn't help me. If you try visiting [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method), it does not satisfy my needs.

**EDITS**:  The generic method I'm trying to call is an extension one. I have unsuccessfully tried the following code, 
`method` remains null

```
     var result = repo.Get();
     Type elementType = 
             Type.GetType("x2o_Care.Models.ViewModels.PatientViewModel");
     MethodInfo method =typeof(AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions) 
                      .GetMethod("ProjectTo", new[] { typeof(IQueryable)});
        MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(elementType);

        var model = generic.Invoke(result.OrderBy(e => true).Take(20), null);
```

Comment: The second link has precisely what you need for the last line. What you have on the second line is not possible, because `var` needs the exact type at compile time.

Comment: Then, is this what you're looking for?  [How to call a generic extension method with reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15927028)?  If not, can you provide a [mcve] for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is exactly what you need. You just need to specify exactly what overload of ProjectTo method you need as there are a few. Make sure to specify all the parameters in GetMethod/

For example:

```
MethodInfo method =typeof(AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions) 
                      .GetMethod("ProjectTo", new[] { typeof(IQueryable),
                          typeof(object), 
                          typeof(Expression<Func<TDestination, object>>[]) 
                        });
```

Here is a list of all the ProjectTo methods:
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/QueryableExtensions/Extensions.cs